# Comparison of two tables using sql

Tags: sql

I have two tables - Table A (id, a1) and Table B (id, b1)
i am joining the two tables on A.id=B.id and want to check for the joined records, if a1 is equal to b1. This is the query that I have used but somehow it isn't giving me results. (PS: duplicate records exist in the Table A for the same id)

```
select A.id, B.id, A.a1, B.b1
from tableA A join
     tableB B
     on A.id = B.id
where concat(A.id, a1) <> concat (B.id, b1)
```

Please let me know whats the error in this. There may be a simpler solution to it but I am not aware of it.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Only tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the `id`s are the same because of the `join`, doesn't this do the same thing?

```
select A.id, B.id, A.a1, B.b1
from tableA A join
     tableB B
     on A.id = B.id
where a1 <> b1;
```

If you are using a database where `CONCAT()` with `NULL` ignores the `NULL` value, then you can use:

```
select A.id, B.id, A.a1, B.b1
from tableA A join
     tableB B
     on A.id = B.id
where coalesce(a1, '') <> coalesce(b1, '')
```

Comment: If a1 is null then a1 <> b1 is false even if b1 is null.

Comment: @Dr.Zim . . . And `concat()` returns `NULL` as well under that circumstance in MySQL.  I suppose this is database-dependent.

Comment: maybe even `not (a1 is null and b1 is null or a1 = b1)`

Comment: in where condition, i put where id is null or id = ' ' or concat (id, a1) <> concat (id, b1)...guess this should cover all scenarios right

Comment: @user3532090 . . . That would seem to cover many scenarios -- especially if empty columns don't contain just spaces.